# sort table with a href link, and store a value in a cookies. Can only use PHP

Tags: php, cookies, href

I have a table, like this
[image]

The titles are to create a cookie, and store a value like "description", when someone clicks the description title.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. When I check the cookie, it sets to the last setcookie which is "deleted". Nothing happens when I click on other links (except page refresh).

```
<table>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "id"); $PHP_SELF?>>ID</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "itemName"); $PHP_SELF?>>Item Name</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "description"); $PHP_SELF?>>Description</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "supplierCode"); $PHP_SELF?>>Supplier Code</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "cost"); $PHP_SELF?>>Cost</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "price"); $PHP_SELF?>>Selling Price</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "onHand"); $PHP_SELF?>>Number On Hand</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "reorderPoint"); $PHP_SELF?>>Reorder Point</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "backOrder"); $PHP_SELF?>>Back Order</th>
       <th><a href=<?php setcookie("orderCookie", "deleted"); $PHP_SELF?>>Delete/Restore</th>
```

requirement:

> Make each column header a link. When the user clicks on the link, it
>   redisplays the records sorted in ascending order on that column value.
>   Store the name of the column last sorted on in a cookie, and use this
>   as the default sorting the next time the user calls view.php. That is,
>   this cookie should be used to "preserve" the view, even between
>   sessions.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
   <th><a href="?orderBy=id">ID</th>
   <th><a href="?orderBy=itemName">Item Name</th>
   <th><a href="?orderBy=description">Description</th>
   <th><a href="?orderBy=supplierCode">Supplier Code</th>


if(isset($_GET['orderBy'])){
   $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
   setcookie("orderCookie", $order); 
   header("Location:view.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers must be sent by PHP before any HTML content is sent. You cannot set cookies, once the first character of html is sent.

You can use javascript/jQuery for this, instead.

EDIT: Help to use javascript to set cookies:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460174/1001641

EDIT 2:
In your code, in the **href** attribute, use this instead:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?r=id"; ?>
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?r=itemName"; ?>
```

and so on.

Now, at the top of your file, use this code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['r']))
{
  $r = $_GET['r'];
}
else
{
  $r = "";
}
setcookie("orderCookie", $r);
?>
```

Comment: hi, this is a php class, so i am not allowed to use javascript or jQuery

Comment: why not? can't you place your javascript just before <table> tag, even if it is a php class?

Comment: found one solution, have a look

Comment: check edit. should i use echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . or header

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41810/discussion-between-naveed-hasan-and-hank99)

Comment: If this answer helped you, then you should select this answer as the correct answer.